# How write a hadoop program using sequenceInput and output file?

Tags: hadoop2

Hello everyone i want to write a hadoop program using a sequencefile input and output file. I tryed to set up `job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class)` but it cause `EOFException`:

I used `HVPI` https://github.com/xmpy/hvpi with `xuggler` to break a video into frames. I want save the frames in a sequence file and save it in `HDFS` to use in another map reduce task.

Another way is write a hadoop custom output file but i don't know how do it.

I followed this tutorial http://hadooptutorial.info/hadoop-sequence-files-example/ but i got `EOFException` on

```
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    int len = WritableUtils.readVInt(in);
    byte[] temp = new byte[len];
    in.readFully(temp, 0, len);     
    ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = 
        new ByteArrayInputStream(temp); 
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(byteStream);
}


16/09/17 17:05:55 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce task executor complete.
16/09/17 17:05:55 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local72686463_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:529)
 Caused by: java.io.EOFException

 at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)       
 at    edu.bupt.videodatacenter.input.ImageWritable.readFields(ImageWritable.java:67)
...
```

More specifically in line in.readFully(temp, 0, len). This is from ImageWritable class. It's from HVPI. I don't made any change. I just used this.

Comment: problably there is something wrong with the custom writable type in the readFields implementation. It's just happen when i use the SequenceFileInputFormat.addInputhPath(job, in).

Answer (score 0):

The error was the custom type implementation. The write method on custom type was wrong. I just     add out.write(byteOutputStream.toByteArray()) and now it's work fine.